# Grade 10 academic math

Tags: geometry

The perimeter of a basketball court is 72m. The difference between its length and its width is 12m. Solve the system to determine the dimensions of the court. 
I keep getting different answerers and can't seem to find the right on. Please help.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you showed your attempts -- then people could try to figure out which _wrong_ things you need to unlearn instead of just showing you the _right_ solution (which you have probably already seen in class for other similar problems, and it hasn't helped you stop doing wrong things in your own attempts).

Answer (score 0):

Let the length be $l$ metres and breadth be $b$ metres.

$2(l+b) = 72$ and $l = b + 12$
These two are the main linear equations.

So, $$2(b+12+b) = 72 \implies 4b + 24 = 72$$
$$4b = 48 \implies b = 12 \implies l = 20$$

So, length and breadth are 20m and 12m respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your question give us the information we need to make two equations.

First: $2l + 2w = 72$.  This shows that the perimeter is 72 m.

Second: $l - w = 12$.  This shows that the difference between its length and width is 12m.

Now we have to solve these equations.  We can rearrange (2) to get $l = 12 + w$.  We then substitute that into (1) and get $2(12 + w) + 2w = 72$.  We can simplify that to get $24 + 4w = 72$.  If we solve for $w$ we get $w = 12$.  Now we need to find $l$.  Just put $w$ into $l = 12 + w$ and we get $l = 24$.

I hope this helps.  You should try asking your teacher with this kind of question.  It's their job to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$2l + 2w=72\\l-w=12$

Now, just solve the second equation for either $l$ or $w$ and plug that into the first equation, then after some more algebraic manipulation you should be able to solve the system